# Manually Create composite.generated.dll

Tags: c1-cms

I'm new to composite C1 CMS and am trying to update a site from 4.1 to 4.2.

I'm running into some build errors because the 4.2 generated.dll file doesn't know about the custom data types etc that were in the 4.1 generated.dll.

Do you have to create the generated.dll manually somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Composite.Generated.dll is usually regenerated when the website restarts.
The quickest way to fix it would be to:

1. put the old DLL back
2. start the site
3. restart the website in IIS

If the DLL isn't updated, there should be errors in the log files

Way #2:

1. Delete the /bin/Composite.Generated.dll
2. Temporary remove DLL-s and App_Code files that were referencing classes from Composite.Generated.dll
3. Start and restart the website
4. Check the log files for errors if the file wasn't re-created

Comment: Looking at the upgrade guide (https://compositec1.codeplex.com/discussions/548579) step 5 it looks like I should overwrite the .generated dll with what came from the version 4.2 folder. 

The problem is, my site doesn't build with the other 4.2 files and the old 4.1 generated dll.


Have you upgraded a site from 4.1->4.2 that has custom data types in it? I'm probably just doing something silly, but haven't figured out what yet.

Comment: I'm guilty of writing the original guide :) The Composite.Generated.dll doesn't contain anything essential for Composite C1 core to start up, it is only third party or c1 packages may reference it to use the dynamic data types defined in the system. Try not overwriting it, it will be automatically overtwritten afterwards anyway.

Comment: I ran into some issues with the references for MVC4 not resolving, I think that was the real issue behind what I was seeing. Thanks for the help!